# Is Esri REST API the same as REST API

Tags: api, arcgis-rest-api, rest

Can an Esri REST API function in QGIS connect to a (non-Esri) REST API or are they significantly different and therefore won't work?

Comment: most likely (non-ESRI) REST API  will not work. Do you have an example? Too many variables. ESRI REST has a standardized model.

Comment: 'An ESRI REST API' doesn't mean anything in this context. Which API are you interested in, ArcGIS Server, ArcGIS Portal, ...?.  A REST API is about *how* you can do a request, e.g. an HTTP GET or POST request. What information goes into that request exactly is not specified A specific REST API, for example the ArcGIS Server REST API, also specifies *what* requests you can do.

Answer (score 5):

REST is a computer industry acronym (REpresentational State Transfer). Most web-based APIs are REST, so no, neither Esri API (Server or Portal) is the same as any other API (or each other). There are, of course, similarities, but that's not enough to make productive use of a REST API, which requires strict adherence to the specification.